# HID Descriptor Dump on Android?

Tags: android, hid

Does anyone know how to dump the HID descriptors for a device on Android?  I'd like to get a parsed dump of several HID descriptors and compare them.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [lsusb command](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/lsusb8.html). There is also a [graphical version on GitHub](https://github.com/chrulri/lsusb-android).

Answer (score 0):

it's easy to list all input devices if you use 'getevent -S' command in adb shell like this:

```
I:\Users\linwei>adb shell getevent -S
add device 1: /dev/input/event6
  name:     "gpio-keys"
add device 2: /dev/input/event2
  name:     "alps"
add device 3: /dev/input/event5
  name:     "7k_handset"
add device 4: /dev/input/event4
  name:     "proximity_sensor"
add device 5: /dev/input/event3
  name:     "accelerometer_sensor"
add device 6: /dev/input/event1
  name:     "7x27a_kp"
add device 7: /dev/input/event0
  name:     "sec_touchscreen"
```

If you want see the detail of one of them. Use 'getevent -i $eventname' to show like this:

```
I:\Users\linwei>adb shell getevent -i /dev/input/event1
 add device 1: /dev/input/event1
 bus:      0000
 vendor    0000
 product   0000
 version   0000
 name:     "7x27a_kp"
 location: ""
 id:       ""
 version:  1.0.1
 events:
   KEY (0001): 0072  0073
 input props:
   <none>
```

So, just find you hid device name and print the info that is possible.
If you want to run these command on Android. You can use Runtime to execute:

```
     th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        private Process exec;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","getevent -i " + device});
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(
                        exec.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                String s;
                while(((s = br.readLine()) != null) && run){
                    ...
                }
                is.close();
                exec.destroy();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }
```